# DropzoneJS: Preview selected image before upload in div as <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I'm currently looking for a way to display a selected image before uploading it via DropzoneJS in a div wrapper as an `<img>` element. Some people here told me that this is possible but I can't find the way. So maybe someone knows how to do this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#upload-image-dropzone").dropzone({
    url: "my-ajax-url",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Move files here to upload",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: !1,
    maxFilesize: 20,
    maxFiles: 1,
    uploadMultiple: !1,
    acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .jpeg",
    init: function() {
      this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        this.files.length > this.options.maxFiles && this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
      })
    },
    success: function() {}
  });
});
```

```css
#upload-image-dropzone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px dotted #222222;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha256-cs4thShDfjkqFGk5s2Lxj35sgSRr4MRcyccmi0WKqCM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="upload-image-dropzone"></div>
<div id="image-preview-container"><img/></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preview the image using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API, once it has been selected in a file-input.

Note that the support for IE 10/11 is partial, and it's not supported by IE9 at all ([ref](https://caniuse.com/#search=filereader))

** In your specific scenario, instead place the "importImage" function inside the "addedfile" listener. https://jsfiddle.net/yzm8v203/3/

```js
function importImage(input) {
  let fileReference = input.files && input.files[0];
  
  if(fileReference){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = (event) => {
   document.getElementById('preview').src = event.target.result;
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileReference); 
    
  }

}

document.getElementById('uploadInput').addEventListener('change', function(){ importImage(this) })
```

```html
<input type='file' id="uploadInput" />
<img id="preview" src="" alt="Image preview" />
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer! But is an answer with my above code snippet possible? Because you're using an input here but I'm a dropzone.

Comment: under the hood, dropzone.js uses file-input, so as I mentioned in the answer, In your specific situation, you'll need to place the  call to the "importImage" inside the "addedfile" listener. look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yzm8v203/3/

Comment: ...image before uploading it via DropzoneJS ... But okay, I'll try it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ha now I understand, but what should be the process? how you want to preview it? like after the drag there should be a button that will submit the upload?

Comment: made it. Thanks!